# postgresql query how to append dups counter to name column

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates, ranking-functions

I have table [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=34092725334ee35adadc59e24345eb3b).

how to find all duplicate records, considering `length(name)=3` ? and append dups counter to the name as a suffix?

Below screenshot,  `Key 6 and 7` has characters length > 3 and when length(name)=3 then **Jay** is there two times so `Key 6 and 7` name should have dups counter as suffix ,  after length(name)=3.
Below is expected for  `Key 6 and 7`

[image]

I'm trying to use below query to get dups but it returns only dup data but not both  `Key 6 and 7` ,

```
select *, left(name,3)||rank() over(partition by left(name,3) order by key) as expected_name
 from (select key, name,rank() over(partition by left(name,3) order by key) as dups, tag
         from label where length(name)>3
      ) a 
 where dups >1
```

Is there a way to get both dups rows so that i can append counter using rank function.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure I'm following, but something like `CASE WHEN Count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY LEFT(name, 3)) > 1 AND ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LEFT(name, 3) ORDER BY key) > 1 THEN LEFT(name, 3) || ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LEFT(name, 3) ORDER BY key) -1 ELSE name END AS name, 
 `?

Comment: @JNevill thanks . helpful to get expected results –

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To append dups counter(row number) to names having name length greater than 3

```
select l.*,
Case when length(name)>3 and 
Count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY LEFT(name, 3)) > 1 
 then new_name
 else name end AS expected_name , 
new_name
from label l
left join 
(select key as key1, LEFT(name, 3) || ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY LEFT(name, 3)  ORDER BY key)
as new_name
from label where length(name)>3 ) name
on l.key=name.key1
```